# Check if file exist and run a batch file in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

This may be a simple question, but I am new to PowerShell and could not find a way to do it. Basically, I have to run a .BAT file if a specified file does not exist. The file name is in a patten like "*mmddyyy*.dat" in a folder, where mmddyyyy is today's month, day(0 prefix if < 10) and year. Pseudo codes would be something like this:

```
 $File = "C:\temp\*mmddyyyy*.dat" # how to parse Get-Date mmddyyyy and build this pattern?
 #if $File exist # check any file exist?
     .\myBatch.bat  # run the bat file, can I run it in hidden mode?
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd recommend making a reusable function like the following:

```ps
function GetDateFileName
{   
    $date = Get-Date
    $dateFileName = "$(get-date -f MMddyyyy).dat"
    return $dateFileName
}
$fileName = GetDateFileName
$filePath = "c:\temp\" + $fileName

if([IO.File]::Exists($filePath) -ne $true)
{
    #do whatever
}
```

Comment: If I want to add two parameters as args to the function and return the result in the format of "{0}{1:d2}{2:d2}{3}{4}" -f arg[0],...,arg[1]. How Can I make the call this function? I got failure by calling GetDateFleName("C:\temp\*", "*.dat").

Comment: `$dateFileName = "{0:MMddyyyy}.dat" -f (Get-Date)` would be a little bit shorter and less convoluted.

Comment: You add the parameters to a function like so:
function foo([string]$foo = "foo", [string]$bar = "bar")
{
  Write-Host "Arg: $foo";
  Write-Host "Arg: $bar";
}

and you call the function like so:

foo "param1" "param2"

Comment: `$dateFileName = "$(get-date -f MMddyyyy).dat"` would be even shorter and less convoluted.  :-)

Comment: You should be using the cmdlet Test-Path in PowerShell, instead of using the .NET File.Exists directly

Comment: See also: [A better way to check if a file exists or not in PowerShell](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31888581/450913)

Answer (score 23):

The command is :

```
test-path .\example.txt
```

Returns True or False

For Docs how about official documentation? That's where I check.
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/scriptcenter/dd742419.aspx

also eggheadcafe.com has a lot of examples:
http://www.eggheadcafe.com/conversationlist.aspx?groupid=2464&activetopiccard=0

Although I haven't tried regex in poweshell this may help you:

http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/33029659/regex-multiline-question.aspx

Comment: how to guild a string based on today's date, in a pattern mmddyyyy? For example "11132009" for today.