# A better way to check if a path exists or not in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

Is there a more concise and less error-prone way in PowerShell to check if a path DOES NOT exist?

This is objectively too verbose for such a common use case:

```
if (-not (Test-Path $path)) { ... }
if (!(Test-Path $path)) { ... }
```

It needs too many parenthesis and is not very readable when checking for "not exist". It's also error-prone because a statement like:

```
if (-not $non_existent_path | Test-Path) { $true } else { $false }
```

will actually return `False`, when the user may expect `True`.

What is a better way to do this?

**Update 1:** My current solution is to use aliases for `exist` and `not-exist` as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31888581/450913).

**Update 2:** A proposed syntax that will also fix this is to allow the following grammar:

```
if !(expr) { statements* }
if -not (expr) { statements* }
```

Here's the related issue in PowerShell repository (please vote up ): https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/1970

Comment: You could use `try{ Test-Path -EA Stop $path; #stuff to do if found } catch { # stuff to do if not found }`

Comment: Related issue: https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/1970

Answer (score 161, accepted):

If you just want an alternative to the cmdlet syntax, specifically for files, use the `File.Exists()` .NET method:

```
if(![System.IO.File]::Exists($path)){
    # file with path $path doesn't exist
}
```

---

If, on the other hand, you want a general purpose negated alias for `Test-Path`, here is how you should do it:

```
# Gather command meta data from the original Cmdlet (in this case, Test-Path)
$TestPathCmd = Get-Command Test-Path
$TestPathCmdMetaData = New-Object System.Management.Automation.CommandMetadata $TestPathCmd

# Use the static ProxyCommand.GetParamBlock method to copy 
# Test-Path's param block and CmdletBinding attribute
$Binding = [System.Management.Automation.ProxyCommand]::GetCmdletBindingAttribute($TestPathCmdMetaData)
$Params  = [System.Management.Automation.ProxyCommand]::GetParamBlock($TestPathCmdMetaData)

# Create wrapper for the command that proxies the parameters to Test-Path 
# using @PSBoundParameters, and negates any output with -not
$WrappedCommand = { 
    try { -not (Test-Path @PSBoundParameters) } catch { throw $_ }
}

# define your new function using the details above
$Function:notexists = '{0}param({1}) {2}' -f $Binding,$Params,$WrappedCommand
```

`notexists` will now behave *exactly* like `Test-Path`, but always return the opposite result:

```
PS C:\> Test-Path -Path "C:\Windows"
True
PS C:\> notexists -Path "C:\Windows"
False
PS C:\> notexists "C:\Windows" # positional parameter binding exactly like Test-Path
False
```

As you've already shown yourself, the opposite is quite easy, just alias `exists` to `Test-Path`:

```
PS C:\> New-Alias exists Test-Path
PS C:\> exists -Path "C:\Windows"
True
```

Comment: If `$path` is "special", like on a Powershell Provider (think HKLM:\SOFTWARE\...) then this will fail miserably.

Comment: @Eris question specifically asks to check if a *file* exists or not

Comment: Definitely, and creating a new cmdlet on the fly is neat. Nearly as unmaintainable as an alias, but still really neat :)

Comment: Nice! I think PS should add native support for this.

Comment: @orad I seriously doubt you'll get them to do that. "Too many parentheses" is a *very* subjective reasoning and doesn't really merit deviating from the language design/specification. FWIW, I also agree with the if/else construct proposed by @briantist as a better alternative if you really hate parentheses that much: `if(Test-Path $path){}else{ # do your thing }`

Comment: @mathias-r-jessen Well, I'm trying anyways. It's a minor but very common thing in PS that needs a little more love IMHO.

Answer (score 55):

The alias solution you posted is clever, but I would argue against its use in scripts, for the same reason I don't like using any aliases in scripts; it tends to harm readability.

If this is something you want to add to your profile so you can type out quick commands or use it as a shell, then I could see that making sense.

You might consider piping instead:

```psh
if ($path | Test-Path) { ... }
if (-not ($path | Test-Path)) { ... }
if (!($path | Test-Path)) { ... }
```

Alternatively, for the negative approach, if appropriate for your code, you can make it a positive check then use `else` for the negative:

```psh
if (Test-Path $path) {
    throw "File already exists."
} else {
   # The thing you really wanted to do.
}
```

Comment: I like the piping here, but your proposed checks for negatives are incorrect without parenthesis, or it will always evaluate to `False`. You need to do it like `if (-not ($path | Test-Path)) { ... }`.

Comment: @orad you're correct! Actually that's a negative of piping in that case. I was lulled into a false sense of security by it not throwing an exception, when it fact it was failing. Calling it the original way throws an exception, making it easier to catch the problem.

Answer (score 16):

Add the following aliases. I think these should be made available in PowerShell by default:

```
function not-exist { -not (Test-Path $args) }
Set-Alias !exist not-exist -Option "Constant, AllScope"
Set-Alias exist Test-Path -Option "Constant, AllScope"
```

With that, the conditional statements will change to:

```
if (exist $path) { ... }
```

and

```
if (not-exist $path) { ... }
if (!exist $path) { ... }
```

Comment: If you want the PowerShell team to add an "exist" alias, you should submit a feature request through Microsoft Connect

Comment: Even though I answered it myself, I accept @mathias-r-jessen's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31896279/450913) because it handles parameters better.

Answer (score 8):

This is my PowerShell newbie way of doing this

```
if (Test-Path ".\Desktop\checkfile.txt") {
    Write-Host "Yay"
} 
else {
    Write-Host "Damn it"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to use `IO.FileInfo` which gives you so much file info it make life easier just using this type:

```
PS > mkdir C:\Temp
PS > dir C:\Temp\
PS > [IO.FileInfo] $foo = 'C:\Temp\foo.txt'
PS > $foo.Exists
False
PS > New-TemporaryFile | Move-Item -Destination C:\Temp\foo.txt
PS > $foo.Refresh()
PS > $foo.Exists
True
PS > $foo | Select-Object *


Mode              : -a----
VersionInfo       : File:             C:\Temp\foo.txt
                    InternalName:
                    OriginalFilename:
                    FileVersion:
                    FileDescription:
                    Product:
                    ProductVersion:
                    Debug:            False
                    Patched:          False
                    PreRelease:       False
                    PrivateBuild:     False
                    SpecialBuild:     False
                    Language:

BaseName          : foo
Target            : {}
LinkType          :
Length            : 0
DirectoryName     : C:\Temp
Directory         : C:\Temp
IsReadOnly        : False
FullName          : C:\Temp\foo.txt
Extension         : .txt
Name              : foo.txt
Exists            : True
CreationTime      : 2/27/2019 8:57:33 AM
CreationTimeUtc   : 2/27/2019 1:57:33 PM
LastAccessTime    : 2/27/2019 8:57:33 AM
LastAccessTimeUtc : 2/27/2019 1:57:33 PM
LastWriteTime     : 2/27/2019 8:57:33 AM
LastWriteTimeUtc  : 2/27/2019 1:57:33 PM
Attributes        : Archive
```

[More details on my blog.](https://blog.vertigion.com/2019/02/27/powershell-file-exists/)

Answer (score 3):

To check if a Path exists to a directory, use this one:

```
$pathToDirectory = "c:\program files\blahblah\"
if (![System.IO.Directory]::Exists($pathToDirectory))
{
 mkdir $path1
}
```

To check if a Path to a file exists use what [@Mathias](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31896279/12969125) suggested:

```
[System.IO.File]::Exists($pathToAFile)
```

Answer (score 2):

After looking at @Mathias R. Jessen's excellent answer, it occurred to me that you don't need to create two new functions. Instead, you can create a wrapper around the native `Test-Path` function with the same name that adds a `-Not` switch:

```
$TestPathCmd = Get-Command Test-Path
$TestPathCmdMetaData = New-Object System.Management.Automation.CommandMetadata $TestPathCmd
$Binding = [System.Management.Automation.ProxyCommand]::GetCmdletBindingAttribute($TestPathCmdMetaData)
$Params  = [System.Management.Automation.ProxyCommand]::GetParamBlock($TestPathCmdMetaData)

$Params += ', [Switch]${Not}'
$WrappedCommand = {
    $PSBoundParameters.Remove('Not') | Out-Null
    [Bool]($Not.ToBool() -bxor (Microsoft.PowerShell.Management\Test-Path @PSBoundParameters))
}

${Function:Test-Path} = '{0} Param({1}) {2}' -f $Binding,$Params,$WrappedCommand
```

E.g.:

```
Test-Path -Path 'C:\Temp'      # True
Test-Path -Path 'C:\Temp' -Not # False
Test-Path -Path 'C:\Txmp'      # False
Test-Path -Path 'C:\Txmp' -Not # True
```

This has a couple of advantages:

1. Familiar syntax: when you're not using the custom switch, syntax is identical to the native command, and when you are it's pretty intuitive what's happening, which means less cognitive burden for the user, and more compatibility when sharing.
2. Because the wrapper is calling the native function under the hood, it will work anywhere the native function does, e.g.:

   ```
   Test-Path -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE'      # True
   Test-Path -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE' -Not # False
   Test-Path -Path 'HKLM:\SXFTWARE'      # False
   Test-Path -Path 'HKLM:\SXFTWARE' -Not # True
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (Test-Path C:\DockerVol\SelfCertSSL) {
    write-host "Folder already exists."
} else {
   New-Item -Path "C:\DockerVol\" -Name "SelfCertSSL" -ItemType "directory"
}
```

Comment: Please add more explanation.

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.