# How do I check if a file is present in a particular location?

Tags: powershell, if-statement

I would just like help writing my `if` statement, I am having a hard time finding information online to do what I would like. Basically I need my if statement to see if the `$file` is located at a specified location (which can be multiple locations if possible). So far I have this:

```
foreach ($file in $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path) {
  if ($file) {  #I need this to search a specific directory or directories
  }
}
```

Comment: The question and code you posted don't make sense. `$MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path` is the full path to the script, which obviously does exist, otherwise the code wouldn't be running in the first place. It's also not a collection, which makes the `foreach` loop pointless.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see if something exists try using the `test-path` command. This will return a true/false value that you can plug into subsequent `if` statements and do what you want respectively.

```
$fileTest = test-path [file path here]
if($fileTest -eq $true){
    #what happens when the file exists
}
else{
    #what happens when the file does not exist
}
```

Comment: if you want to make sure it's a file and not a directory add: `-PathType Leaf`

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a .NET method:

```
if(![System.IO.File]::Exists($file)){
  # File exists
}
```

[A better way to check if a path exists or not in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31888580/a-better-way-to-check-if-a-file-exists-or-not-in-powershell)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to know if the file exists at one of the locations then use:

```
if( ( (test-path 'c:\testpath1\test.txt','c:\testpath2\test.txt') -eq $true).Count)
{
"File found!";
}
```

If you want to know where the file is found then execute the test-path for each path seperatly.

```
if( ( (test-path 'c:\testpath1\test.txt') -eq $true).Count)
{
"File found at testpath1!";
}
if( ( (test-path 'c:\testpath2\test.txt') -eq $true).Count)
{
"File found at testpath2!";
}
```