# How to supply argument to value of New-Alias command?

Tags: powershell

I wish `Get-ChildItem -force` to get executed when I type `ll` and I have this in my `profile.ps1`:

```
New-Alias -Name ll -Value Get-ChildItem -force
```

However, when I type `ll`, I can see that the `-force` argument is not being used. What am I doing wrong?

Edit: What I really wish to achieve is to show all files in a folder, even if they're hidden. And I wish to bind this to `ll`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot do that with aliases. Aliases are really just different names for commands, they cannot include arguments.

What you *can* do, however, is, write a function instead of using an alias:

```
function ll {
  Get-ChildItem -Force @args
}
```

You won't get tab completion for arguments in that case, though, as the function doesn't advertise any parameters (even though all parameters of `Get-ChildItem` get passed through and work). You can solve that by effectively replicating all parameters of `Get-ChildItem` for the function, akin to how PowerShell's own `help` function is written (you can examine its source code via `Get-Content Function:help`).

Answer (score 1):

To add to [Joey's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42108380/712649), this is [how you can generate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31888580/a-better-way-to-check-if-a-path-exists-or-not-in-powershell/31896279#31896279) a proxy command for `Get-ChildItem` (excluding provider-specific parameters):

```
# Gather CommandInfo object
$CommandInfo = Get-Command Get-ChildItem

# Generate metadata
$CommandMetadata = New-Object System.Management.Automation.CommandMetadata $CommandInfo

# Generate cmdlet binding attribute and param block
$CmdletBinding = [System.Management.Automation.ProxyCommand]::GetCmdletBindingAttribute($CommandMetadata)
$ParamBlock = [System.Management.Automation.ProxyCommand]::GetParamBloc($CommandMetadata)

# Register your function
$function:ll = [scriptblock]::Create(@'
  {0}
  param(
    {1}
  )

  $PSBoundParameters['Force'] = $true

  Get-ChildItem @PSBoundParameters
'@-f($CmdletBinding,$ParamBlock))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't. For this reason a few years ago I created a PowerShell module that does this. It is on the gallery and it is open source.

I was looking for the same experience. This is how to use it:

```
Add-Alias ls 'ls -force'
Add-Alias add 'git add'
```

Gallery:
https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/posh-alias/

Github:
https://github.com/giggio/posh-alias