# How to use FINDSTR in PowerShell to find lines where all words in the search string match in any order

Tags: powershell, boolean-logic, findstr

The following `findstr.exe` command *almost* does what I want, but not quite:

```
findstr /s /i /c:"word1 word2 word3" *.abc
```

I have used:

- `/s` for searching all subfolders.
- `/c:`

  > Uses specified text as a literal search string
- `/i` Specifies that the search is not to be case-sensitive.
- `*.abc` Files of type abc.

The above looks for `word1 word2 word3` as a *literal*, and therefore only finds the words in *that exact order*.

By contrast, **I want *all* words to match *individually*, in *any order* (AND logic, conjunction)**.

If I remove `/c:` from the command above, then lines matching *any* of the words are returned (OR logic, disjunction), which is not what I want.

Can this be done in PowerShell?

Comment: Hi, I believe you should be using [`Select-String`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string) to accomplish this (in Powershell).

Comment: I'm overwhelmed by the response and great answers. Thanks to all. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `Select-String` to do a regex based search through multiple files.

To match all of multiple search terms in a single string with regular expressions, you'll have to use [a lookaround assertion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4389644/regex-to-match-string-containing-two-names-in-any-order):

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.abc -Recurse |Select-String -Pattern '^(?=.*\bword1\b)(?=.*\bword2\b)(?=.*\bword3\b).*$'
```

In the above example, this is what's happening with the first command:

> ```
> Get-ChildItem -Filter *.abc -Recurse
> ```
>
> `Get-ChildItem` searches for files in the current directory
>   `-Filter *.abc` shows us only files ending in `*.abc`
>   `-Recurse` searches all subfolders

We then pipe the resulting FileInfo objects to `Select-String` and use the following regex pattern:

> ```
> ^(?=.*\bword1\b)(?=.*\bword2\b)(?=.*\bword3\b).*$
> ^              # start of string  
>  (?=           # open positive lookahead assertion containing
>     .*         # any number of any characters (like * in wildcard matching)
>       \b       # word boundary
>         word1  # the literal string "word1"
>       \b       # word boundary
>  )             # close positive lookahead assertion
>  ...           # repeat for remaining words
>  .*            # any number of any characters
> $              # end of string
> ```

Since each lookahead group is just being asserted for correctness and the search position within the string never changes, the order doesn't matter.

---

If you want it to match strings that contain *any* of the words, you can use a simple non-capturing group:

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.abc -Recurse |Select-String -Pattern '\b(?:word1|word2|word3)\b'
```

> ```
> \b(?:word1|word2|word3)\b
> \b          # start of string  
>   (?:       # open non-capturing group
>      word1  # the literal string "word1"
>      |      # or
>      word2  # the literal string "word2"
>      |      # or
>      word3  # the literal string "word3"
>   )         # close positive lookahead assertion
> \b          # end of string
> ```

---

These can of course be abstracted away in [a simple proxy function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31888580/a-better-way-to-check-if-a-path-exists-or-not-in-powershell/31896279#31896279).

I generated the `param` block and most of the body of the `Select-Match` function definition below with:

```
$slsmeta = [System.Management.Automation.CommandMetadata]::new((Get-Command Select-String))
[System.Management.Automation.ProxyCommand]::Create($slsmeta)
```

Then removed unnecessary parameters (including `-AllMatches` and `-Pattern`), then added the pattern generator (see inline comments):

```
function Select-Match
{
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName='Any', HelpUri='http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113388')]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0)]
        [string[]]
        ${Substring},

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
        [Alias('PSPath')]
        [string[]]
        ${LiteralPath},

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Any')]
        [switch]
        ${Any},

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='Any')]
        [switch]
        ${All},

        [switch]
        ${CaseSensitive},

        [switch]
        ${NotMatch},

        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [ValidateSet('unicode','utf7','utf8','utf32','ascii','bigendianunicode','default','oem')]
        [string]
        ${Encoding},

        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [ValidateCount(1, 2)]
        [ValidateRange(0, 2147483647)]
        [int[]]
        ${Context}
    )

    begin
    {
        try {
            $outBuffer = $null
            if ($PSBoundParameters.TryGetValue('OutBuffer', [ref]$outBuffer))
            {
                $PSBoundParameters['OutBuffer'] = 1
            }

            # Escape literal input strings
            $EscapedStrings = foreach($term in $PSBoundParameters['Substring']){
                [regex]::Escape($term)
            }

            # Construct pattern based on whether -Any or -All was specified 
            if($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq 'Any'){
                $Pattern = '\b(?:{0})\b' -f ($EscapedStrings -join '|')
            } else {
                $Clauses = foreach($EscapedString in $EscapedStrings){
                    '(?=.*\b{0}\b)' -f $_
                }
                $Pattern = '^{0}.*$' -f ($Clauses -join '')
            }

            # Remove the Substring parameter argument from PSBoundParameters
            $PSBoundParameters.Remove('Substring') |Out-Null

            # Add the Pattern parameter argument
            $PSBoundParameters['Pattern'] = $Pattern

            $wrappedCmd = $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.GetCommand('Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility\Select-String', [System.Management.Automation.CommandTypes]::Cmdlet)
            $scriptCmd = {& $wrappedCmd @PSBoundParameters }
            $steppablePipeline = $scriptCmd.GetSteppablePipeline($myInvocation.CommandOrigin)
            $steppablePipeline.Begin($PSCmdlet)
        } catch {
            throw
        }
    }

    process
    {
        try {
            $steppablePipeline.Process($_)
        } catch {
            throw
        }
    }

    end
    {
        try {
            $steppablePipeline.End()
        } catch {
            throw
        }
    }
    <#

    .ForwardHelpTargetName Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility\Select-String
    .ForwardHelpCategory Cmdlet

    #>

}
```

Now you can use it like this, and it'll behave almost like `Select-String`:

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.abc -Recurse |Select-Match word1,word2,word3 -All
```

Answer (score 6):

Another (admittedly less sophisticated) approach would be to simply daisy-chain filters, since the order of the words doesn't matter. Filter your files for one word first, then filter the output for lines that also contain the second word, then filter *that* output for lines that also containt the third word.

```
findstr /s /i "word1" *.abc | findstr /i "word2" | findstr /i "word3"
```

Using PowerShell cmdlets the above would look like this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter '*.abc' -Recurse | Get-Content | Where-Object {
  $_ -like '*word1*' -and
  $_ -like '*word2*' -and
  $_ -like '*word3*'
}
```

or (using aliases):

```
ls '*.abc' -r | cat | ? {
  $_ -like '*word1*' -and
  $_ -like '*word2*' -and
  $_ -like '*word3*'
}
```

Note that aliases are just to save time typing on the commandline, so I do not recommend using them in scripts.

Comment: The advantage of this approach is conceptual simplicity. For performance reasons it may be worth sticking with `findstr` in this particular case (assuming that character-encoding issues don't get in the way).

Comment: The answer also works and is simple. However, i have accepted another answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Note:

- The first part of this answer does *not* solve the OP's problem - for solutions, see [Mathias R. Jessen's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43451196/45375) and [Ansgar Wiecher's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43452387/45375); alternatively, see the bottom of this answer, which offers a generic solution adapted from Mathias' code.

  - (Due to an initial misreading of the question), **this part of the answer uses *disjunctive* logic** - matching lines that have at least *one* matching search term - which is **the only logic that `findstr.exe` and PowerShell's `Select-String` (directly) support**.
  - By contrast, **the OP is asking for *conjunctive* logic**, which requires additional work.
- This part of the answer may still be of interest with respect to translating `findstr.exe` commands to PowerShell, using `Select-String`.

---

The **PowerShell equivalent of the `findstr` command** from the question, **but without `/c:`** -
`FINDSTR /s /i "word1 word2 word3" *.abc`

- is:

  (Get-ChildItem -File -Filter *.abc -Recurse |
  Select-String -SimpleMatch -Pattern 'word1', 'word2', 'word3').Count

- `/s` -> `Get-ChildItem -File -Filter *.abc -Recurse` outputs all files in the current directory subtree matching `*.abc`

  - Note that wile [`Select-String`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string) *is* capable of accepting a filename pattern (wildcard expression) such as `*.abc`, it doesn't support *recursion*, so the separate `Get-ChildItem` call is needed, whose output is piped to `Select-String`.
- `findstr` -> `Select-String`, PowerShell's more flexible counterpart:

  - **`-SimpleMatch`** specifies that the `-Pattern` argument(s) be interpreted as ***literals* rather than as *regexes*** (*regular expressions*). Note how they defaults differ:

    - `findstr` expects *literals* by default (you can switch to regexes with `/R`).
    - `Select-String` expects *regexes* by default (you can switch to literal with `-SimpleMatch`).
  - `-i` -> (default behavior); like most of PowerShell, **case-*in*sensitivity is `Select-String`'s default** behavior - add `-CaseSensitive` to change that.
  - `"word1 word2 word3"` -> `-Pattern 'word1', 'word2', 'word3'`; **specifying an *array* of patterns looks for a match for *at least one* of the patterns on each line** (*disjunctive* logic).

    - That is, all of the following lines would match: `... word1 ...`, `... word2 ...`, `... word2 word1 ...`, `... word3 word1 word2 ...`
- `/c` -> `(...).Count`: `Select-String` outputs a **collection of objects** representing the matching lines, which this expression simply counts.
  The objects output are **[`[Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.powershell.commands.matchinfo(v=vs.85).aspx) instances**, which not only **include the matching line**, but **metadata about the input and the specifics of what matched**.

---

A solution, building on [Mathias R. Jessen's elegant wrapper function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43451196/45375):

**[`Select-StringAll`](https://gist.github.com/mklement0/356acffc2521fdd338ef9d6daf41ef07) is a conjunctive-only *wrapper* function around the disjunctive-only `Select-String` cmdlet** that uses the exact same syntax as the latter, with the exception of not supporting the `-AllMatches` switch.

That is, `Select-StringAll` requires that *all* patterns passed to it - whether they're regexes (by default) or literals (with `-SimpleMatch`) - match a line.

Applied to the OP's problem, we get:

```
(Get-ChildItem -File -Filter *.abc -Recurse |
  Select-StringAll -SimpleMatch word1, word2, word3).Count
```

<sup>Note the variations compared to the command at the top:</sup>

- The `-Pattern` parameter is implicitly bound, by argument position.
- The patterns are specified as barewords (unquoted) for convenience, though it's generally safer to quote, because it's not easy to remember what *needs* quoting.

Answer (score 0):

The following will work if you DO NOT HAVE ANY OF THE WORDS REPEATED IN THE SAME LINE as:
word1 hello word1 bye word1

```
findstr /i /r /c:"word[1-3].*word[1-3].*word[1-3]" *.abc
```

If repeated word1/word2/word3 is not there, or you do want those occurrences in your result, then can use it.