# Check to see if a directory exists if not do something

Tags: powershell

I am pretty new to powershell, this question is going to sound super basic i imagine. but i want my code to check to see if the user has a file in their app data. if the script does not find it. the script will start a process.

i have tried wmi methods but i feel that there is a faster simpler almost one line way to do this i cant think of

```
$app = Test-Path C:\Users\bobsaget\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0
 if($app = "False"){ Start-Process 'an executable' "/s"}
```

it changes $app to be false and i see where its happening i just dont fully understand what i am doing wrong with my IF statment.

Answer (score 3):

1. The `=` operator in PowerShell assigns a value. For comparison, you want `-eq`, not `=`.
2. If the `$app` variable contains a boolean value, you don't want to compare it to the string `False` - you should say `-not $app` (i.e., the `$app` variable contains the boolean value `$false`).
3. You usually don't need `Start-Process` to invoke a program. Just use the program's command line. If the executable's name or its path contains white space, prefix it with the `&` (invocation) operator.
4. You don't really need the `$app` variable if you're not going to use it later. You can simply write this:

   ```
   if ( Test-Path "C:\Users\bobsaget\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0" ) {
     & "C:\Path\my program.exe" /s
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

[A better way to check if a path exists or not in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31888580/a-better-way-to-check-if-a-path-exists-or-not-in-powershell)

There is a couple ways to do this if you look at the article above. 
The most basic way to check if a file exists and then execute code would be this:

```
if (Test-Path $path){
   do stuff 
}
```

Or this if you want it to execute some code when a path doesn't exist:

```
if (!(Test-Path $path)){
   do stuff
}
```